# How do I remove characters from the end of a string till I reach a certain character?

Tags: php

I am trying to remove letters from the end of the string until the string ends with certain characters.

I have strings like the following:

```
$filename=test1/test.jpeg;
$filename2=project/test2/test1112.jpeg;

// The file name length could vary.
```

I want to get the file folder so the value will be `test1` or `project/test2`

I have tried

```
$folder = substr($filename,-4)
```

but that's static. How do I do it dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use php's [dirname](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function

```
$filename = 'test1/test.jpeg';
$filename2 = 'project/test2/test1112.jpeg';


var_dump(dirname($filename));
var_dump(dirname($filename2));
```

Answer (score 2):

might be faster to do

```
$folder = substr($filename, 0, strrpos('/'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's specifically file names you're looking for, PHP's inbuilt function `dirname()` is [probably what you want](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php).

For a more generic answer to the question posed, it's certainly possible to work backwards through the string with `substr()` till you reach a certain character.

Here's a generic "remove characters from the end of a string till I reach a certain character" function:

```
<?php

$str = 'This is a few words in some sort of order; it makes some sort of sense.';

function find_to_last_char($str, $char) {
  $reversed_string = strrev($str);
  $char_pos = strpos($reversed_string, $char);
  if ($char_pos === false) return $str; // character not present
  $trim = substr($reversed_string, $char_pos);
  return strrev($trim);
}

echo find_to_last_char($str, ';');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to split the string by /

```
$file_parts_ary = explode("/", $filename);
```

If the last element in the array is the filename, then you know that all the previous ones are the path. You can combine them again or pull out one specific one.

```
$file_path_ary = array_pop($file_parts_ary);   // remove the filename
$file_path = implode("/", $file_path_ary);  // Put the rest of the path back together
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function called strrpos which returns the last occurrence of an element in a string. So after that you can use substr($strin,0,strrpos("/"))

OK?

Answer (score 1):

[PHP pathinfo function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is what you're looking for. Here's an example based on your code:

```
<?php
    $filenames = array(
        'test1/test.jpeg',
        'project/test2/test1112.jpeg'
    );

    foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
        echo pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . "\n";
    }
```

resulting in:

```
    test1
    project/test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the string, remove everything up to the first slash, then re-reverse it to get the original without the filename.

Comment: Talk about not efficient.

Comment: At least this answer shows one way to do it.